# Reset my DispatcherTimer

Tags: wpf

I'm using WPF application and I have reminder every hour from 7 AM tell 3 PM every day, it is running every hour even if the user closed the window it still show up after one hour using DispatcherTimer.

my issue is after 3 PM it closed and it keep checking tell next day to count one hour after 7 AM to display the window but it is not.

it display directly after 7 AM. how I can fixed it, please assist

my code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public int _mCollapsed;
        public Window1 WindowLink1;
        public ReminderWin ReminderWin1;

        public TimeSpan start = new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0);
        public TimeSpan end = new TimeSpan(15, 0, 0);

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _mCollapsed = 1;
            WindowLink1 = new Window1();
            ReminderWin1 = new ReminderWin();
        }
       private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
            if (now > start)
            {
                System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
                dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);
                dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
                dispatcherTimer.Start();
            }
private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
            if ((now > start) && (now < end))
            {                               
                BitmapImage _image = new BitmapImage();
                _image.BeginInit();
                _image.UriSource = new Uri(@"test123.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                _image.UriCachePolicy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.BypassCache);
                _image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                _image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
                _image.EndInit();
                ReminderWin1.image1.Source = _image;

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ReminderWin1.WindowState);

                if (ReminderWin1.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed || ReminderWin1.Visibility == Visibility.Hidden)
                {
                    ReminderWin1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                }
            }
            else if (now > end)
            {
                if (ReminderWin1.Visibility == Visibility.Visible || ReminderWin1.Visibility == Visibility.Hidden)
                {
                    ReminderWin1.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        }
```

Comment: Can you formulate your question more clearly? I don't understand exactly what you want.

Comment: My scenario is I'm using a dispatcher to display reminder window every hour between 7 Am tell 3 PM. my issue is that on 7 AM next morning I found that window popups randomly before completing one hour. means for example 8 AM.

Comment: Please any assist

Comment: Reduce the time from 1 hour to 1 minut, to be more easy,  and start debugging.

Comment: That's what I did with no luck, it keep running next day at 7 AM instead of 8 AM, I need to reset dispatcher timer in order to count one hour.

Comment: I got the solution here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6280ef8c-ff34-4a77-8b2b-244c1c068b28/reset-my-dispatchertimer